# Akka-http: Illegal URI reference: Invalid input ':'

Tags: scala, curl, akka, httprequest, akka-http

I would like to make http request to a website, where format is like `https://abcde-abcde.abcde.abcde.abcde.abcde.com/abcde` and I am ending up getting following error for the following code.

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.client.RequestBuilding.Get

val url = "https://abcde-abcde.abcde.abcde.abcde.abcde.com/abcde"
val getData = Get(url)
```

error message:

```
"message":"Illegal URI reference: Invalid input ':', expected 'EOI', '#', '?', !':' or slashSegments (line 1, column 7): \"https://abcde-abcde.abcde.abcde.abcde.abcde.com/abcde\n      ^"
```

Can somebody help me what is wrong with this piece of code. I am just simply doing this https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-and-response.html

** UPDATE **
instead of passing `url` like `Get(url)`, I wrote whole string
like `Get("https://abcde-abcde.abcde.abcde.abcde.abcde.com/abcde")` , and it worked. I think somehow string re-eval is the problem. Any idea ?

Comment: Is this really the URL you are using? No `:` in the real URL?

Comment: yes, exactly, that is why I also confused.

Comment: there is only one `:` in the url which is right after the https, and not any more.

Comment: @GaëlJ I think string eval is the problem, but could not fully figured out. Updated post.

Comment: From the error message, seems like a linebreak at the end of the URL.

Comment: but the code is exactly same as above, there is no line break, i am just passing a string.